# How to calculate the surface area of a 3d mesh

Tags: 3d, mesh, area, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

I am making a project in unreal engine 5, and need to find out the surface area of a mesh.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6CIW.png)
in this example, I got a basic plane I set up, and, I need to calculate the surface area of the wings, as well as the surface area of the entire plane.

it's my first time dealing with a problem like this, so, I tried to search the internet, couldn't find anything useful, so I decided to ask this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward by using the `UProceduralMeshComponent`. In Blueprints (or C++), you can copy the Static Mesh to the Procedural Mesh using the following node:

[image: Copy Procedural Mesh from Static Mesh Component]

You can then write a function that takes a pointer to `UProceduralMeshComponent` and use the following API: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Components/ProceduralMesh/

The function of interest is `Get Section from Procedural Mesh` which is also exposed to Blueprint scripting if that's what you prefer:

[image: Get Section from Procedural Mesh]

Now it's just a matter of looping over all the triangles and calculating the vector product (size of the cross product of the triangle's vectors) and summing them up.